# Vlookup function assistance needed in VB script, using String for most recent sheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

my VB script obtains the sheet name of the most recent sheet in the workbook, storing the sheet name as a string, however when I reference this string in a Vlookup function, Excel cannot locate the sheet. The sheet name is in date format, so the most recent sheet is yesterday's date (in Australian date format), '08-06-2021'. The macro runs, but when it comes to running the VLookup function, it cannot find the sheet and interestingly the following message appears:

Cannot find "2021". Copy from:

And opens a window to locate the Spreadsheet, and then select the Worksheet within the spreadsheet. For fun I renamed the '08-06-2021' sheet to just '2021' to see if that would work. This also didn't work, and the error was even more unusual, as it is now trying to locate a sheet name that doesn't exist. The new message was:

Cannot find "C1322021". Copy from:

As mentioned, there is no sheet with the name C1322021. Here is the relevant VB code:

```
Dim wsData1 As Worksheet  
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim rWorkSheet As String

Dim i 

  i = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1
  rWorkSheet = Worksheets(i).Name

  Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row + 1
  Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

       For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
       With ActiveSheet.Cells(Lrow, "M")

            sNotes = "=VLookup(C" & Lrow & rWorkSheet & "!C:N, 12, False)"

                ActiveSheet.Cells(Lrow, "M") = sNotes

        End With
```

Appreciate any assistance with this, as it has me stumped!

TIA,

Michael

Comment: shouldn't it be `"=VLookup(C" & Lrow, rWorkSheet & "!C:N, 12, False)"`? and if your worksheet contains a space it should be ``"=VLookup(C" & Lrow, "'" & rWorkSheet & "'!C:N, 12, False)"`` Also it should be `ActiveSheet.Cells(Lrow, "M").Formula = sNotes`.

Comment: You're right, there was a comma missing, and I also needed the parentheses even though there aren't spaces in the sheet name. This is what is working for me, following your suggestions:

                sNotes = "=VLookup(C" & Lrow & "," & "'" & rWorkSheet & "'" & "!C:N, 12, False)"

Btw this lines seems to work without the '.Formula' on the end:

                    ActiveSheet.Cells(Lrow, "M") = sNotes

Thanks for your excellent and timely help!

Comment: I wrote it as an answer so you can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional comma and the worksheet name needs to be in single quotes.

```
sNotes = "=VLookup(C" & Lrow & "," & "'" & rWorkSheet & "'" & "!C:N, 12, False)"
ActiveSheet.Cells(Lrow, "M").Formula = sNotes
```

Also `ActiveSheet.Cells(Lrow, "M")` defaults to `ActiveSheet.Cells(Lrow, "M").Value` but to write formulas you should use `.Formula`. Even if it might work without this way it is more reliable and clear to everyone reading the code.